# Pre-process to change the name of a file field in node

Tags: nodes, theming

I have a file field in a node and I would like all instances of this field to have a different display name.

I use the file field to upload images that users can download - e.g. flower.jpg, horse.jpg.

Instead of the field displaying " flower.jpg",I want it do display the text "download".

The machine name of my field is "field_source" and the name of my theme is " kickstart". The content type is " resource".

What would a pre-process function in my template.php look like to do this?

This is as far as i get:

```
function kickstart_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  if($vars['type'] == 'resources'){
    $vars['content']['field-source']['#title'] = 'download';
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to change the label maybe the module string overrides is your best option https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides

you can also edit your settings.php file to change the label https://www.drupal.org/node/522036

Answer (score 0):

The easiest programmatic way to do this is to override the field template file for your specific field.

1. Create a file named `field--field-source.tpl.php` (assuming that the machine name of your field is field_source).
2. Copy and paste the code for the default Drupal field template file (which is called `field.tpl.php`, and is very well documented in terms of the variables it receives). Customize it to your needs.

Use the `dpm()` function (enable `Devel`) to troubleshoot the variables that the new template file receives.

Information about [Drupal's template files](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656).